# Block Code is not working on magento CMS page

Tags: php, magento, product

I am showing products from a category on a CMS page by using following code but it not showing anything on front end please have a look and let me know what wrong i am doing

I have used this code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3"template="catalog/product/listhp.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Does it work with the default list.phtml rather than your custom one?

Comment: No its also not working with default list.phtml

Answer (score 2):

**Option #1**

If the below is your code:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3"template="catalog/product/listhp.phtml"}}
```

> Give a SPACE between category_id="3" and template="..."

Updated code must be:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="3" template="catalog/product/listhp.phtml"}}
```

Let me know if that works.

[Editing the answer as it can be more than 1 options]

**Option #2**

> 1. Navigate to System > Permissions > Blocks
> 2. Add the block - Enter "catalog/product_list" in the field
> 3. Set Allowed to Yes

Clear cache and check.

Hope this helps someone. Happy to Help!

Happy Coding...

Comment: Did you clear cache? If not, delete the folders present in /var/

Comment: Yes i have cleared the cache and checked it again but no luck.

Comment: What is there in your listhp.phtml file can you share that? Do you have a category with category ID=3 can you share any screenshots if possible as a part of your post description? Which CMS Page have you created ? Are you able to print HELLO or any TEXT on your CMS Page?

Comment: I have some other contents on the page that are working perfectly. just block code is not working:
 here is the CMS page screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/CWVGEVodLVuT  @Shivani
and this is category screenshot: http://screencast.com/t/mVjN1r6lIQ7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101180/discussion-between-shivani-and-shoaib-fareed).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue Xabby described.

Option #2 by Shivani worked like a charm. Did not know these permissions were necessary. In case someone is wondering, these are the steps:

1. Navigate to System > Permissions > Blocks
2. Add the block - Enter "catalog/product_list" in the field
3. Set Allowed to Yes